# How can I use sed to replace a string with the content of a variable, when the variable has whitespace?

Tags: bash, sed

How can I use sed to replace a string with the content of a variable, when the variable has whitespace?

For example

```
sed 's_3_4 5_g'
234
```

returns 24 54, but

```
replace="4 5";  sed 's_3_'$replace'_g'
234
```

gives me the error

```
sed: 1: "s_3_4": unterminated substitute in regular expression
```

Answer (score 2):

Just quote the variable expansion:

```
sed 's_3_'"$replace"'_g'
```

Comment: Or for slightly cleaner syntax, you can remove some of the over-quoting and just do `sed "s_3_${replace}_g"`. And, personally, I find that use of `_` a bit jarring, preffering `sed "s/3/${replace}/g"` (or `;` instead of `/`), but whatever...